# Cakephp 1.3: How to migrate into my Article Tabel - Function

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller, migration

I have an application that used another php cms system, which I am now transferring to CakePHP 1.3. I've come to a point where I need to transfer all my old articles in `tblnewsarticles` to my new CakePHP table `articles`. The tables have different fields, but I have been able to map all the ones I need to my new table. I created the following temporary `migrate` function in my `ArticlesController class` to perform this operation for me, but cannot have the data to save into my table. Everything seems to be OK, including I have done tests with `debug($data)` and `debug($articles)` and it shows the data, but I cannot save anything. I cannot see anything wrong with this so any help is appreciated...

```
//TEMPORARY FUNCTION THAT WILL BE DELETED/DEACTIVATED AFTER MIGRATION
function migrate(){                
        // FOR TESTING PURPOSES I SET LIMIT=1, BUT I HAVE OVER 4000 ARTICLES TO TRANSFER
    $articles = $this->Article->query(
        "SELECT articleID,subcategoryID,article_title,article_html,article_date,image_extension FROM tblnewsarticles LIMIT 1;"
    );

    foreach($articles as $article){
        $data['Article']['id'] = $article['tblnewsarticles']['articleID'];
        $data['Article']['published'] = 1;
        $data['Article']['title'] = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_title'];
        $data['Article']['body'] = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_html'];
        $data['Article']['main_image'] = 'cat_'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['subcategoryID'].'/'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['articleID'].'.'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['image_extension'];
        $data['Article']['category_id'] = $article['tblnewsarticles']['subcategoryID'];
        $data['Article']['user_id'] = 2;
        $data['Article']['created'] = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_date'];

        if (!empty($data)) {
             $this->Article->create();
             $this->Article->save($data);                       
             $this->Session->setFlash('Migration processed successfully');
        }else{                      
             $this->Session->setFlash('Unsuccessful');
        }
    }   
}
```

**======== THIS IS WHAT I DID THAT WORKED FOR ME ================**

```
function migrateArticle(){

$articles = $this->Article->query(
                    "SELECT articleID,subcategoryID,article_title,article_html,article_date,image_extension FROM tblnewscategories;"
    );

    foreach($articles as $article){

    $categoryID = $article['tblnewsarticles']['subcategoryID'];
    $articleID = $article['tblnewsarticles']['articleID'];
    $articleTitle = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_title'];
    $articleSlug = str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($articleTitle));
    $articleBody = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_html'];
    $articleImage = 'cat_'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['subcategoryID'].'/'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['articleID'].'.'.$article['tblnewsarticles']['image_extension'];
    $articleDate = $article['tblnewsarticles']['article_date'];

   $this->Article->query("INSERT INTO categories (id, published, title, slug, body, main_image, category_id, user_id, created) VALUES('$articleID', '1', '$articleTitle', '$articleSlug', '$articleBody', '$articleImage', '$categoryID', '2', '$articleDate');");   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not just do this at the database level? It'd likely be far less code.

Comment: Database level? Sorry, but what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to load 4000 records all at once and then process them individually. It's probably easier with a single database query that copies everything. Something like

```
INSERT INTO articles
    (id, published, title, body,
     main_image,
     category_id, user_id, created)
    SELECT articleID, 1, article_title, article_html,
          CONCAT('cat_', subcategoryID, '/', articleID, '.', image_extension),
          subcategoryID, 2, article_date
    FROM tblnewsarticles;
```

(untested, of course)

Comment: Thanks Arjan, based on your suggestion I was able to accomplish what I needed.... thanks a lot... See my question with the EDIT